# Es6 formatting Error?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, ecmascript-6

This string variable define in js.

```
bodycontent = 'Hello ' + studentName + '%0D%0AThe course ' + courseName
                + ' is using the TEAMMATES System to collect feedback.%0D%'
                + '0ATo \'join\' the course, please go to this Web address: '
                + encodeURIComponent(uri) + '%0D%0A*If prompted to log in, '
                + 'use your Googleaccount to log in. If you do not '
                + 'have a Google account, please create one from the '
                + encodeURIComponent('https://accounts.google.com/NewAccount')
                + '%0D%0A*The above link is unique to you. Please do not '
                + 'share it with your classmates.%0D%0ANote that If you '
                + 'wish to access TEAMMATES without using your Googleaccount, '
                + 'you do not need to \'join\' the course as instructed '
                + 'above. You will still be able to submit/view feedback '
                + 'by following the instructions sent to you by TEAMMATES at the '
                + 'appropriate times. However, we recommend joining the courseusing '
                + 'your Google account, because it gives you more convenient '
                + 'access to all your feedback stored in TEAMMATES.%0D%0A%0D%0A'
                + 'If you encounter any problems when using the system, you can '
                + 'email TEAMMATES support team at teammates@comp.nus.edu.sg.%0D%0A%0D%0A'
                + 'Regards,%0D%0ATEAMMATES Team.';
```

For exceeding 125 characters in a line i break it to the next line by using + now the problem is when i converted this into ES6.

```
        bodycontent = `Hello ${studentName}%0D%0AThe following feedback session is ${status}%0D%0A`
                   + `Course: [${Id}]${courseName}%0D%0AFeedback Session Name: ${Id}%0D%0A`
                   + `The link of the feedback for the above session, please go to this Web `
                   + `address: ${encodeURIComponent(uri)}%0D%0A*The above link is unique to you.`
                   + `Please do not share it with others.%0D%0A%0D%0AIf you encounter any problems`
                   + `when using the system, you can email TEAMMATES support team at teammates@comp.nus.edu.sg.%0D%0A%0D%0ARegards,%0D%0ATEAMMATES Team.`;
```

This shows me erro "Strings must use singlequote  quotes" in each line which doesn't contain variable.

I can break the line like this also

```
bodycontent = `Hello ${studentName}%0D%0AThe following feedback session is ${status}%0D%0A
                    Course: [${Id}]${courseName}%0D%0AFeedback Session Name: ${Id}%0D%0A
                    The link of the feedback for the above session, please go to this Web 
                   address: ${encodeURIComponent(uri)}%0D%0A*The above link is unique to you.`
                   ......
```

But the problem is i am getting "\n" addition of newline in my string which i don't want kindly tell me the efficient way to break the line without adding \n in my string.

Answer (score 1):

Any whitespace included in a template literal will also be included which is why you are receiving newlines.  **This is the expected behaviour of template literals**.  This **feature** of a template literal allows it to be used to create strings over multiple lines without the need for workarounds, e.g.:

```
$('div.post').html("<h3>Some title here</h3> " +
  "<p>Lorem ipsum doloramet, onsectetur adipiscing elit " +
  "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore...");
```

becomes:

```
$('div.post').html(`
  <h3>Some title here</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum doloramet, onsectetur adipiscing elit
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore...
`);
```

---

It seems like you only want to run over multiple lines as a result of the length of your String, so *this issue is about your **subjective** text editing preference*.

> **Suggested Soution:**
>
> Have you tried using ***text-wrap*** in your IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Use the awesome prefixed template literals with `common-tags` package. You can also copy the implementation if you don't use npm.

The [`oneLine`](https://github.com/declandewet/common-tags#oneline) tag will change all newlines and indents to one whitespace. If you want to strip the last whitespace as well, use [`oneLineTrim`](https://github.com/declandewet/common-tags#onelinetrim).